# Aggregate based on a condition in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My database is in MongoDB. I have a list of logs of users. A log is as follows:

```
{
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a176fa24d96415280e22cc8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-12-10T15:36:45.566Z"),
    ... ...
}
```

And I have a list of users:

```
{
    "currentName" : "anonym"
    ... ...
},
{
    "currentName" : "Laurent Dupuis"
    ... ...
}
```

I have the following shell to sort and list the users by their number of logs:

```
db.getCollection('logs').aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $lookup: { from:"users", localField:"_id", foreignField:"_id", as:"user" } }, 
    { $sort: { count: -1 } }
]);
```

However, I would like to not consider the users whose `currentName` is `anonym` to build that list. Does anyone know how to modify that shell?

Comment: The `$lookup` has another version syntax to specify a _pipeline_, where you can specify additional conditions on both the collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [specify-multiple-join-conditions-with--lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with--lookup)

```
db.logs.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },    
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "let": { uId: "$_id" },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $not: { "$eq": [ "$currentName", "anonym" ] } },
                { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$uId" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "user"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6knm73tjYrI)**

Comment: Thank you... but in your solution, is it possible to not show `{ "_id": 1, "count": 1, "user": [] }`? I guess this matches the anonym, right?

Comment: Yes, you can, you need to add a match query https://mongoplayground.net/p/kNg7DzgOnXo